# How to sum 3 cells only if one of both are not blank otherwise leave blank the cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm looking for a way to make sum only if one of both cells are not blank otherwise leave the sum cell blank. I'm working w/ Google Sheets.
Here is my formula for the moment: =SUM(L6;+K7;-J7) the same formula will be on 90 cells on the same column.
If anyone could help!
Sincerely!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use the combination of IF() and AND() methods in google sheet :

```
=if(and(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2)),"",SUM(A2:C2))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the contribution but I got a "formula parse error".

Comment: Try using ; instead of , in the formula.

Comment: there is no instead formula in Google Sheets

Comment: Hi, Louis, he means that you should change the commas to semicolons in the code.  Also check that you have replaced the cell names (A2) with the correct ones (such as J7, K7, L6) for your sheet.

Comment: Okay, my bad, I mistaken so it worked by replacing , by ;. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Thank you for your help!